# Возможно ли использовать переменную класса как тип другого класса php

Tags: php

Например

```
require_once "../Request.php";

class Test {

  protected $token = '';
  protected $botname = '';
  protected Request $request; //// тут ошибка
}
```

Comment: Похоже, что нет. Видимо только в аргументах методов можно юзать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Не возможно. 
Есть такое предложение для PHP 7.x но пока нет одобрения на реализацию. [Подробнее здесь](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/property_type_hints)

Если тебе необходимо устанавливать специфично значение для свойство то используй методы класса. Например

```
public method setRequest( Request $request ) {
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если цель - добиться подсказок от IDE, то можно написать так:

```
/**
 * @var Request
 */
protected $request;
...
```